# VBA Filter by 2 months ago

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to filter by 2 months ago (i.e. Dec 2016) and doesn't work. But, if I go in excel select to edit current filter and press ok, it will show right results. What is the issue?

My code:

```
With Worksheets("SER Common")
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, "<=" & CDate(Evaluate("EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)"))
End With
```

Comment: it happened to my once, try `.Range("A1").AutoFilter 1, "<=" & CDbl(Evaluate("EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)"))`

Comment: Cheers, it works!

Answer (score 0):

one line is enough:

```
Worksheets("SER Common").Range("A1").AutoFilter field:=1, criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(Evaluate("EOMONTH(TODAY(),-2)"))
```

Comment: Yup, but it will not work. The Excel filter has its own idea and opinion about dates and their format.

Answer (score 0):

That's another way to do it (except the conversion to dbl) in the comments from @Shai Rado:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & Format(DateAdd("m", -2, Now()), "yyyy-mm-dd")
    End With

End Sub
```

The idea is to format it to `yyyy-mm-dd`, this format is recognizable by Excel. Plus with `DateAdd` it looks easier to understand it.